# What is the difference between ".class element" and "element.class"?

Tags: css

Is there a difference between `.class element` and `element.class` in a CSS selector?

I had always been shown `element.class` but just the other day came across a CSS file at work that had `.class element` and wanted to know if this was just a style choice (in which case I would make my changes match), or if there was a specific reason (in which case I would not necessarily want to make my changes match).

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`element.class` selects all `<element />`s with that class. `.class element` selects all `<element />`s that are descendants of elements that have that class.

For example, HTML:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='content'></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class='footer'></div>
</div>
```

For example, CSS:

```
div.wrapper {
  background-color: white; /* the div with wrapper class will be white */
}

.wrapper div {
  background-color: red;   /* all 3 child divs of wrapper will be red */
}
```

Comment: So use the latter we can just skip one level and avoid more nesting, to keep it simple.

Answer (score 13):

"element.class" selects elements that have the given class.

".class element" selects all elements that are children of anything with the given class.

Example:

```
<div class="foo">
    <p>...</p>
</div>
```

`div.foo` would select the div, while `.foo p` would select the child paragraph.  It should be noted that without specifying direct child via the ">" selector, this will traverse the entire document tree when looking for children.

Answer (score 1):

I like to think it as follows:

```
1) a, b  =   a OR b
2) a  b  =   a AND b (on that order)
3) a.b   =   a.b     (on that order)
```

2, 3) **a b** is not the same as **b a**.
2) Elements belonging to **a** and **b** simultaneously, i.e. nor **a** or **b** elements. Is a range selection.
3) **a** elements of **b** class. Is an exact selection.

Answer (score -3):

very simple example:

HTML:

```
<ul class="a">
<li>1</li>
<li class="a">2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.a li{color:blue;}
li.a{color:red;}
```

Comment: How is this different/better than the [already accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6023440/215552)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Before answering a question, please review other answers to the question and only provide an answer of your own if you have information to add that hasn't already been provided by another poster. In this case, your answer would not be considered very valuable since you've not explained anything at all, but it's especially egregious since there's a very well written answer from *five years ago* that's been accepted and upvoted.