# difference between .class element and element.class in css?

Tags: html, css

Following this tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_nesting.
Confused about why they used .marked p instead of p.marked (why is it when I change it to p.marked the text doesn't go white).

I looked through previous posts like [what is the difference between ".class element" and "element.class"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023419/what-is-the-difference-between-class-element-and-element-class) but couldn't understand the answers as they used terminology that i didn't understand like children and descendent.

could someone please provide a simple example on how these work. Thanks.

Comment: Quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/7UX8c/1/

Comment: The answer is very clear, why are you confused? Consider the document as a Tree or a hierarchy, there are ascendants and descendants. `a b` selector, selects the **b** children of **a**, and `a.b` selects the **a** elements which have `b` class.

Answer (score 3):

Its really simple.

**Take this HTML code**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

The First type is  **element.class**

**example:**

```
div.container{
 background:red;/*This will set the background to the div WITH class "CONTAINER"*/
}
```

The Second type is   **.class element**

**example:**

```
.container div{
   background:blue;/*This will set the background to the div INSIDE the CONTAINER class*/
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please read some basic rules of CSS selectors, like what is in the following:

```
.foo --> selects all element which have class foo
#foo --> selects an element which its id is foo
p.foo --> selects all P elements which have class foo
p#foo --> selects a P element which its id is foo
.foo p --> selects all P elements which are resident inside all elements which their class is foo
and so on...
```

Answer (score 0):

`element.class` applies the attribute to the element itself whereas `.class element` does so to the elements inside the class.

In simple words, if you have `element.class` and you say `<element class="class" />` then, the css you make will be applied to that element. On the other hand, if you have `.class element` and then you do

```
<element class="class">
<element />
</element>
```

then you css would apply to the element that is inside.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is .class assign the property to all the elements irrespective of their type, ie it can be applied to div, span,  p etc

But the element.class the property is applied to that element only

Answer (score 0):

when ever you write, .class elementname, it means you are targetting element name with in the .class tag. Suppose you have ".test p", for that you would write, 

`<div class="test">Happened<p>Something</p></div>`

And When you write, element .class, you are trying to target on .class element present inside the element's tag. Suppose you have "p .test", for that you would write, 
`<p>Something, <div class="test">Happened</div></p>`