# CSS style partially applying to button in React component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

- I have a button with a className 'actions'
- This button shows the
  css styling from '.actions' but not '.actions button' . I expect both to be included.
- This syntax here works for every element except the button.

The full code is at: https://github.com/keithmacinnis/for-play-activity-browser

**Activity.module.css**

```
  .item {
    margin: 1rem 0;
  }
  
  .image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  }
  
  .image img {
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  
  .content {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1rem;
  }
  
  .content h3 {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    color: #2c292b;
  }
  
  .actions {
    padding: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .actions button {
    font: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #77002e;
    border: 1px solid #77002e;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  
  .actions button:hover,
  .actions button:active {
    background-color: #ffe2ed;
  }
```

**Activity.js**

```
import css from "./Activity.module.css";
import Card from "./Card";

function Activity(props) {
    return (
        <li className={css.item}>
            <Card>
                <div className={css.image}> 
                    <img src={props.activity.image} alt={props.activity.title} />
                </div>
                <div className={css.content}>
                    <h3>{props.activity.title}</h3>
                    <address>{props.activity.address}</address>
                    <p>{props.activity.description}</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button className={css.actions}>Join Activity</button>
                </div>
            </Card>
        </li>
    );
}
export default Activity;
```

Again, I'm unsure why my button receives the stylings for padding and text-align, but the eight properties that follow are ignored.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between ".class element" and "element.class"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023419/what-is-the-difference-between-class-element-and-element-class)

Comment: No, but that is a nice thread.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have much experience with creating selector combinations that include an element type and className, but I just did a little experimenting on my own, and it appears that these may be considered sibling selectors (as opposed to one being the child of the other). Also, it seems like the element type may have to come before the className.

It looks like if you write the selectors like one of these two ways, it should work:

```
button ~ .actions {
    *styles*
}

button + .actions {
    *styles*
}
```

You can read more about combinators here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Comment: So; this worked for the button but the change broke the image. 

In other words; by switching the order I got more of the desired styles for the button; but this syntax style broke the styles for the image.

Answer (score 0):

To use .class selector for a specific element. You need Start with the element name first, then write the period (.) character, followed by the name of the class... like this

```
Button.actions {
font: inherit;
cursor: pointer;
color: #77002e;
border: 1px solid #77002e;
background-color: transparent;
padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
border-radius: 4px;
}
```

If that doesn't work. It might be a problem with the browser using your previous css version from the cash and not the updated styling. To solve it use this:

Ctrl + F5 On Mac OS (in Chrome) use: Cmd + Shift + R .

This will force your browser to reload and refresh all the resources related to the website's page.

Comment: So, if I apply that change to:
```  
.image img  {
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
```
it breaks it.
If I apply that style to the button, it works?

Comment: No the img selector is correct. Just change the button.actions one... if it doesn't work. I'm sending you an other solution. Relates to the browser problems

Comment: I've edited my answer. The second solution should work

Answer (score 0):

It was fixed by this change in Activity.js :

new code:

```
<div className={css.actions}>
    <button >Join Activity</button>
</div>
```

old code:

```
<div>
    <button className={css.actions}>Join Activity</button>
</div>
```